# What Salesforce flow components are translateable

Tags: process-builder, translation

I'm trying to figure out what component types in a flow are translateable and which are not. It seems like the Text component is translateable via Translation Workbench - but it looks like you can not translate Phone, Email, Address and a number of other flow components. If this is a limitation then I have not seen any documentation of this limitation. Pretty frustrating you can't translate these core data labels in a flow.